# How to switch to the old LogCat in Android Studio Dolphin

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio Dolphin introduced a new LogCat but it is not working sometimes. Is there any way to disable it and switch back to the old LogCat?

I couldn't find where to change it back in the preferences. Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To switch back to old **Logcat**:

Settings > Experimental > Don't check the > Enable new Logcat tool window | at the end.

[image]

Comment: Aww, it worked. How did I miss this?! Thank you so much. The new logcat is not showing any logs when connected to the emulator sometimes. Better to use the old one.

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/logcat-in-dolphin-version-1ae7f5f687f4